# Woocommerce checkout - how to make select2 and xhr updating work together?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the list of cities as select

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_checkout_city_fields' );
function override_checkout_city_fields( $fields ) { 
    
    // Define here in the array your desired cities (Here an example of cities)
    $option_cities = array(
         '' => __( 'Select city' ),
        'City1' => 'City1',
        'City2' => 'City2',
);
    
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['options'] = $option_cities;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['options'] = $option_cities;
    return $fields;
}
```

Also I update the checkout form data

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'awoohc_add_script_update_shipping_method' );
function awoohc_add_script_update_shipping_method() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                $(document.body).on('updated_checkout updated_shipping_method', function (event, xhr, data) {
                    
                    $('input[name^="shipping_method"]').on('change', function () {
                        
                        $('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper').block({
                            message: null,
                            overlayCSS: {
                                background: '#fff',
                                'z-index': 1000000,
                                opacity: 0.3
                            }
                        });
                        $('select#billing_city').select2();     
                    });
                    var first_name = $('#billing_first_name').val(),                      
                        phone = $('#billing_phone').val(),
                        email = $('#billing_email').val(),
                        city = $('#billing_city').val(),                        
                        address_1 = $('#billing_address_1').val(),                                              

                    $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").html(xhr.fragments[".woocommerce-billing-fields"]);
                    $('select#billing_city').select2(); /*THERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!!!*/   
                    $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_first_name"]').val(first_name);                  
                    $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_phone"]').val(phone);
                    $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_email"]').val(email);  
                    $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_city"]').val(city);  
                    $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_address_1"]').val(address_1);                                                 
                    $('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper').unblock();                                  
                });
            });
        
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I noted where is the problem
If I don't paste select2() there, the select appears like simple select, not select2. But if I try  to change or delete address, when it's a wrong letter for example, the all form is starting to update, doesn't save new values 50%, and appears another one cities select on the top of the page, doesn't allow to change anything. I tested many parts of the code, the conflict is here - between select2 and xhr updating of the cart.
How is possible o fix it? We need both - address updating and select2

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('select#billing_city').selectWoo();
```

[Here](https://developer.woocommerce.com/2017/08/08/selectwoo-an-accessible-replacement-for-select2/) you can see full documentation about it

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.